# No one will get dinged if this isn't solved, so please don't fly away!

Tags: riddle, animals, symbols

I found a message on a nature walk. It warned me there was a wild gathering out and about. But instead of saying what to be careful of, the message only gave me nine clues. They said each symbol given could be combined, as type 1 but not 2 or 3, to give me the group on the loose.

> 1. A symbol of belief
>      Where to choirs some talk
>      With a minor adjustment
>      Of a circle on top
> 2. I am my brother
>      But my brother is not me
>      If you fill me for vacation
>      A new hint will you see
> 3. A friend to ensure
>      All work you have done
>      You’ll find me easily
>      If you fill the start of one
> 4. Go North East
>      And cross my line
>      Or tilt number one
>      And aim toward the sky
> 5. A chasm you’ll find
>      Between my friends
>      I mark a beginning
>      But also an end
> 6. I wave at you for glory
>      Or to signal defeat
>      Given my color
>      Your enemies might think I’m neat
> 7. From late June to late July
>      You may find me crabby
>      For another perspective
>      Tilt and arrange apostrophes
> 8. I share a trait with the hint above
>      However, I run in the fall
>      Loyal and kind are some of my traits
>      While shyness and worry can be my downfalls
> 9. I bring things together
>      Creating most pairs
>      When things go together
>      I’m usually there

What was this message trying to say was about?

Comment: Please let me know if there are better tags for this- I went with what the puzzle's about, but if it counts as a specific kind of puzzle (other than riddle) just let me know.

Comment: In #2, is the "brother"/"bother" difference intentional?

Comment: @puzzledPig No, it was a typo. Thanks for pointing it out, I've fixed it now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is

> WOLF PACK

These describe

> Wingding symbols (hence the title of 'dinging' and 'flying')

See [this table](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-3OLxlxZS6QE/TZc4Pm6uVxI/AAAAAAAAAGU/EPbgnMVXPqw/s400/wingdings1.jpg) for translation

1. A symbol of belief
   Where to choirs some talk
   With a minor adjustment
   Of a circle on top

> A cross - symbol of the church - with a circle is the Celtic cross = W

2. I am my brother
   But my brother is not me
   If you fill me for vacation
   A new hint will you see

> White square - a square is a rectangle but not vice versa and if you fill it then it marks a holiday check = O

3. A friend to ensure
   All work you have done
   You’ll find me easily
   If you fill the start of one

> If you fill 0 (start of 1) you get a black circle = L

4. Go North East
   And cross my line
   Or tilt number one
   And aim toward the sky

> Sagittarius symbol = F

5. A chasm you’ll find
   Between my friends
   I mark a beginning
   But also an end

> A space - end of one word, start of the next

6. I wave at you for glory
   Or to signal defeat
   Given my color
   Your enemies might think I’m neat

> Waving white flag is either a symbol of victory of surrender = P

7. From late June to late July
   You may find me crabby
   For another perspective
   Tilt and arrange apostrophes

> Cancer symbol (21st June to 22nd July) = A

8. I share a trait with the hint above
   However, I run in the fall
   Loyal and kind are some of my traits
   While shyness and worry can be my down falls

> Virgo zodiac sign characteristics = C

9. I bring things together
   Creating most pairs
   When things go together
   I’m usually there

> & - 'and' symbol = K

Giving

> WOLF PACK

Certainly a 'wild gathering'

Comment: 1, 4, and 7 are spot on! As is your guess on the title. :) As a small hint, 5 is quite different from the other 8. On clue 8, you're close but you've got the wrong symbol.

Comment: @Kendra got 5 :P Are 6 and 8 incorrect?

Comment: 5 is correct! On 6, you're close but slightly off point. As for 8, I amend that you're _really_ close, just slightly not right.

Comment: Ah, and your thoughts for 2 are slightly off as well. The symbol itself is completely different, but the translated letter is quite similar.

Comment: @Kendra ah got 6... unsure on most of the rest sadly

Comment: @Kendra solved! Nice puzzle!

Comment: That's it! Right on!